# Why does C# TryParse not handle NaN?

Tags: c#, tryparse

I have some common methods for parsing with default value overrides when reading in some old Fortran data.  Occasionally the data has `NaN (Not a number)` where there should be a numeric value.  I expected that the TryParse would see the string "NaN" and fail to parse.  However, TryParse successfully parses and places `NaN` in for the numeric value.  Is this expected behavior?  If this is expected, are there any other "gotcha" values that I should be looking for?

```
    public static double GetDoubleFromString(string s, double defaultOnFailure = 0)
    {
        //Must be here due to TryParse returning NaN to d and result is set to true below
        if (s.Contains("NaN"))
        {
            log.Warn(string.Format("String contained NaN, returning defaultOnFailure {0} string was {1}", defaultOnFailure, s));
            return defaultOnFailure;
        }

        var d = defaultOnFailure;
        if (!double.TryParse(s.Trim(), out d))
        {
            log.Warn(string.Format("Failed to parse double from string returning defaultOnFailure {0} string was {1}", defaultOnFailure, s));
        }

        return d;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I feel that it should be mentioned, that this only happens for double, long and int do not return the NaN value.  See the example code below, the Common.... code is just formatted Console.WriteLine or stops for console execution.  See screenshot below for output.

```
    public static void NanTestMain()
    {
        Common.WriteBlankWithTitle("Test parse NaN");
        string s = "NaN";

        Common.WriteBlankWithTitle("NaN to Int");
        int i;
        var intSuccess = int.TryParse(s, out i);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Int parse of {0} parse = {1}", i, intSuccess));

        Common.WriteBlankWithTitle("NaN to Double");
        double d;
        var doubleSuccess = double.TryParse(s, out d);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Double parse of {0} parse = {1}", d, doubleSuccess));

        Common.WriteBlankWithTitle("NaN to Long");
        long l;
        var longSuccess = long.TryParse(s, out l);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Long parse of {0} parse = {1}", l, longSuccess));

        Common.Pause();
    }
```

[image: Results of Update Code]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx):

> The *s* parameter can contain [NumberFormatInfo.PositiveInfinitySymbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positiveinfinitysymbol.aspx), [NumberFormatInfo.NegativeInfinitySymbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativeinfinitysymbol.aspx), or [NumberFormatInfo.NaNSymbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nansymbol.aspx) for the culture indicated by provider.

There are three "special" values to look out for. However, the last few words are key - depending on the current culture, you might see something other than `"NaN"`!

Comment: And with each day I find I know less.  Thank you for answering (with links) all my questions.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of those symbols until you asked this question, either. You might also like to see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26428080/3140 for information on other options to `Double.TryParse`, depending on your use case.

Comment: This seems very wrong to me. I have to add code test for these special values.  I would think it very rare that you really want this behavior.  At least for my purposes, I'm finding prepending a zero to the value to parse solves the problem.  "0NaN" or "0bad" throws expected error. "07.3" is expected 7.3.  If you want "" to throw an error, this does not work.  In most cases for me getting zero in that case is a benefit.

Answer (score 4):

[Double.NaN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx) is a valid value for a double, so this is normal. 
There is also negative and positive infinity. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double_fields(v=vs.110).aspx) for other possible 'special' values.

Comment: Jacob's answer was slightly closer with the MSDN link, this is still useful.